# Which Scanners or Scanner/Printers work "plug & play" with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS? Epson Perfection V39 does not, though my now broken 1200U did

Tags: printing, scanner

Which Scanners or Scanners/Printers will work with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LS, using XSane or Document Scanner software? My Epson Perfection 1200U gave me years of service, using Document Scanner, but has now developed a fault. I have an Epson Perfection V39, but it will not work with Ubuntu, infuriatingly it does work with Windows, which I try to avoid using. In purchasing a new scanner or scanner/printer, how can I tell which ones will work with Ubuntu?

Comment: There is no single accurate, updated, central list. The community would welcome volunteers who want to get together and compile such a list. Look for SANE compatibility. Look also for proper reviews of the hardware. And be sure to purchase from a vendor with a generous return policy in case your research results are in error.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This question will probably get closed because it is too open ended and subject to different opinions. Nevertheless, just to give you some useful information, I've had very good experiences with HP Printers. Here is a [list of compatible HP Printers](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) that are officially supported for Linux by HP.

Comment: besides the above: we do not provide hardware recommendations "how can I tell which ones will work with Ubuntu?" google brand + "Ubuntu"

Comment: Have you tried searching for **Perfection V39** in the page" http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX ? Have you tried following the instructions and installing the driver? If you ask a question detailing what you tried and how "but it will not work with Ubuntu" then may be we can help you getting your printer/scanner to work.

Comment: If the above link does not work, try: https://epson.com/Support/wa00821 and click on **Linux Drivers**.

Comment: @Rinzwind  We know that (barring firmware bugs) any MFD vended in the past 5 years will very, very likely work for scanning with Ubuntu. 5 years is not a cut-off point. 10 years is not over-optimistic.

Answer (score 1):

Try HP Printers/Scanners. Ubuntu 20.04.3 comes with hplip (ver. 3.20.3)
Look here wich is supported: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index
Im using a HP Deskjet 4100 and it works out of the box, without doing anything. Only i have to do is connect the Printer via WLAN to my Router, thats it.

Comment: @ user535733 An accurate and updatable list exists at https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan/issues. Ubuntu 21.04 users are given sane-airscan by default. That is a measure of the regard it is held in. @user250143 Buy any MFG that is AirPrint-compatible manufactured in the past 5 years. This is not an opinion. It is a fact.